# Tx and Rx network metrics

Tags: bandwidth, link-utilization, network-measurement

Rx means Receive, and Tx means Transmit. I need to know how can i calculate link utilization (Bandwidth utilization) from these metrics ?, do i need to average them or getting maximum ?

[image: Rx & Tx values]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you express utilization as the higher of Rx and Tx.  If your link bandwidth is asymmetrical, you would calculate it for each direction.

Since utilization is expressed in percentage of maximum bandwidth, you need to calculate the measured bandwidth used, which is

`BW(meas) = Bits(rx or tx)/time period`.

Then utilization is

`Utilization = BW(meas) / BW(link)  * 100`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot calculate bandwidth utilization from that data. It is showing you number of packets received or transmitted since the last time the counters were reset.

It does not show you:

1. The average size of the packets
2. The time interval since the counters were reset
3. The bandwidth of the link (although I presume you know that)

You need to know how many bits were transferred versus how many bits could have been transferred during a time interval to calculate bandwidth utilization.

Inbound and outbound bandwidth utilization are usually calculated and reported separately.

Comment: when i have inutilization (from Inbound) and oututilization (from outbound), can i calculate total link utilization ?